# Having little green kittens about something

Tags: meaning, metaphors

I was very surprised when I first came across this saying. Using google I've found a total of two instances of it, and dictionaries or ngram come up empty.

> My wife **is having little green kittens about** me going solo
> tonight. *[he is asking for someone to join him]* [link](https://nwdiveclub.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=11736)
>
> I'm also reasonably sure the EU would **have had little green kittens
> over** this idea. *[poster is expressing his doubts on the truth of a news article]* [link](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?p=35109425#p35109425)

In both cases the context suggested it means to be strongly opposed to something or [*edit*] to freak out.

Is this an existing expression? Does anybody know where it comes from?

*Edit: apparently, some people prefer blue kittens:*

> I've always heard the expression "Don't have little blue kittens!" as in don't get all excitable, but I've never actually seen a blue kitten!
> [link](http://archive.today/2018.03.30-023911/http://www.reocities.com/rainforest/1200/kennels2.html)

Comment: Come to think of it, both instances also support the meaning of being worried or throwing a fit. There's not too much context anyway but just for the record, I'll add the links.

Comment: I don't think *be strongly opposed to something* is inherently part of the meaning of the idiom. The bride's mother might be having kittens about her daughter's upcoming wedding - which by tradition the mother is often expected to arrange, even if she has limited experience at organising large-scale social gatherings. But that certainly wouldn't imply she was opposed to the wedding taking place (or even, opposed to *herself* being the one who has to organise it). But your cited "green" variant doesn't really add anything of semantic significance - it's just a jocular little "flourish".

Comment: Don't have a cow, man

Comment: Hello, 333. Two examples on the internet almost certainly means that this is not standard English – in fact, so far from it that it's off-topic on ELU.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth One of my questions was: Is this an existing expression? A negative answer does not make my question off-topic, and I wouldn't know where else to ask it. And judging by the answers given so far, there's enough to be said about the saying, or parts of it, to not dismiss it based on purely on statistics.

Comment: 'Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic' is a close-vote reason. Just two hits on the internet and no references found in dictionaries is pretty clear. // The standard idiom 'be having kittens' has been covered here before.

Comment: I suspect it is an instance of the commingling of symbolic analogies.  The effluvium of an individual suffering from intestinal discomfort is often considered to have a verdigris hue.  As to the kitten part, don't have a cow.

Comment: The references to green kittens are somewhat quixotic; not standard.  There must be a term for modifying existing truisms where they are changed but not botched (are not mixed metaphors, so to speak). I find this kind of question to be a challenge, frankly....

Comment: @Lambie A botched mixed metaphor is called a [malaphor](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2017/05/24/malaphors/)

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth There is still the matter of etymology, which I can't ask about at ELL. Is that still off-topic?

Comment: The fact that the expression isn't common enough to be considered an idiom is controlling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression *[to have kittens](https://www.etymonline.com/word/kitten)* meaning to lose one's temper only dates back to the beginning of the twentieth century, so the chances of its dating back to some age of primordial ignorance when women actually feared giving birth to feline offspring approach zero.

Those puzzled by the origin of the expression have apparently never witnessed a cat giving birth. It is not a quiet affair. The adjectives "little green" simply augment the expression and give it a rhythmic ring.

Comment: When I read the expression, my mind invariably combines images of the cat giving birth as mentioned here, with the iconic diner scene from *Alien*, nicely parodied in *Spaceballs* (granted, said creature was not green).  Not sure if that is the intent, but it certainly conveys an exaggerated sense of worry and fitfulness either way.

Answer (score 8):

There's an existing expression in British English "to have kittens":

> "TO HAVE KITTENS - For anyone to confess 'nearly to have had kittens' is a dramatic way of admitting how anxious and scared he had been. For us it is just a metaphor, and no one would dream of taking it literally. Yet the phrase itself goes back to times when women were really worried that, instead of giving birth to a child, they would bring forth kittens.
>   <sub>[The Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/3/messages/139.html)</sub>

Comment: Yes, indeed. And I think green kitten, is just an "exaggerator" [my word], and would be similar to "to have a [colour] cow". That said, green kittens are a "thing": apparently, there have been some green kittens, which can read about online.

Comment: Some people seem to have blue kittens as well, so I guess the colour is indeed just for extra flavour.

Comment: I've always heard the expression "Don't have little blue kittens!" as in don't get all excitable, but I've never actually seen a blue kitten!      http://archive.today/2018.03.30-023911/http://www.reocities.com/rainforest/1200/kennels2.html

Comment: @user33321 Flavor?  Green kittens taste different than normal-color kittens?  Good thing, I guess, given how hairy and scratchy normal kittens taste.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like a mash-up of two different phrases, ***little green apples*** and ["***have kittens***"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+kittens).

The first appears in various expressions; the most familiar may be ["sure as God made little green apples"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sure-as-god-made-little-green-apples), which means that something is very certain (Dictionary.com), but also [*for the love of little green apples*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22for%20the%20love%20of%20little%20green%20apples%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS696US697&oq=%22for%20the%20love%20of%20little%20green%20apples%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.5216j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) (apparently substituting the thing God surely made for God's name) and [***shit little green apples***](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS696US697&ei=NhLJWtCyEJnljwS3pb3QAw&q=%22shit%20little%20green%20apples%22&oq=%22shit%20little%20green%20apples%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...9042.9902.0.10133.6.6.0.0.0.0.100.490.5j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.dfOX9FRfQOs). That last is very similar in meaning to "have kittens" which, as [@Laurel's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/440500/177853) mentions, is a phrase similar to "have a fit" meaning something like "become upset" or "be very angry" (The Free Dictionary).

Combining the two phrases in this way may be a way of evoking the cruder "little apples" phrase, or it could just be a way of making the "kittens" expression more colorful (pretty much literally). It is also possibly intended to emphasize how certain it is that the kittens will be had, playing on the "certainty" meaning of the longer "little green" expression. Since the combined phrase isn't common, the exact meaning should be gleaned from context.

A bit of evidence for the combination of these phrases:

"Kittens" substituted into "for the love of little green apples":

> For the love of **little green kittens**, get rid of that Stinker motor.
>   —[Great Scott, forum post, Traxxas.com, 04-02-2009](https://forums.traxxas.com/showthread.php?467200-Mech-Speed-Control-Replacement&s=c72be39a0aa085db0bf6dfd3524e1a7b&p=3896238&viewfull=1#post3896238)

"Kittens" substituted into "shit little green apples":

> This sentiment and the 'no snitching' garbage makes me so angry I might shit **little green kittens**.
>   —[ace_of_something, "Don't talk to the police. Ever" forum post, *The Escapist*, 18 February, 2009](http://www.escapistmagazine.com/forums/jump/18.88585.1363435)
>
> I have been known to shit **little green kittens on occassion** :-)
>   —[Kimmie, "stupid question but" forum post, *Cloth Diaper Nation*, 09-16-2010](http://I%20have%20been%20known%20to%20shit%20little%20green%20kittens%20on%20occassion%20:-))
>
> Personally, I'd shit **little green kittens** if my "infotainment system" was hooked directly into the car's computer in any way - especially if that system had any wireless handshake capabilities.
>   —[Fatesrider, "The state of the car computer: Forget horsepower, we want megahurtz!" forum post, *ars technica*, May 17, 2017](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?p=33340817&sid=49081de8b85b6821cbdcbf630d5b1de2#p33340817)
>
> Training NO is extremely simple. I won't say how because people will crap little green kittens.
>   —[DarrinGreene, "What is your 'I use an E-Collar Because...' story" forum post, *retrievertraining.net*, 09-18-2017](http://www.retrievertraining.net/forums/showthread.php?178418-What-is-your-quot-I-use-an-E-collar-because-quot-story&p=1901594&viewfull=1#post1901594)

It's probably not a coincidence that all these examples are from various discussion fora, where conversational participants come from all over the world and pick up and play with idioms from folks well outside their physical neighborhood. This would help explain how the relatively US-centric "little green apples" gets combined with the relatively British "have kittens".

Comment: I might be prepared to go along with an allusion to ***little green men***, because they're inherently scary aliens/gremlins, which at least has some semantic connection with *having kittens = being discombobulated / upset / scared*. But your connection to *sure as God made little green apples* sounds far too tenuous to me.

Comment: Both kittens and little green apples are cute (or at least cutesy), and "little green apples" and "little green kittens" have the same cadence, so they go together in my mind. YMMV.

Comment: I don't think green apples are cute. Proverbially (and in real life, as I recall from my youth) eating them gives you a real belly-ache.

Comment: Poking around for further evidence, I found a more direct link between "little green apples" and having kittens, which actually probably plays on the belly-ache you mention. I still think little green apples are cute, even if they're not good eatin'—similar to kittens, actually.

Comment: *"Kittens" substituted into "shit little green apples"*? Isn't "shitting kittens" already a standard phrase?

Comment: Could well be, @Randal'Thor. I don't personally use any of the "shitting" phrases, but there are plenty of variations on the theme (have a cow, shit bricks, lay an egg, etc.) so it makes sense to me that folks would occasionally mix and match them for effect.